# Mutate only applies to the value of the first column

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to remove a substring from the values of a column, my data looks something like this:

```
LBL       Var1      Var2
name1       1        12
name1_A     1        13
name1_B     2        10
name2       1        11
name2_A     2        10
name2_B     3        9
```

I have already created a function that works on a single string, but when I try to mutate the data frame it shows the result of the first row and does not apply on the rest of the rows. What am I doing wrong?

This is the function that I have created so far:

```
remExt <- function(x){
  y <- str_split_fixed(x,"_",2)
  return(y[1])
}
```

I have tried the function with a single string and it works perfectly:

```
string1 <- "Yes_No"

res <- remExt(string1)
print(res)
```

[1] "Yes"

I try the mutate with the following instruction:

```
df %>% mutate(newLBL = remExt(df$LBL))
```

And I get the following result:

```
LBL       Var1      Var2   newLBL
name1       1        12    name1
name1_A     1        13    name1
name1_B     2        10    name1
name2       1        11    name1
name2_A     2        10    name1
name2_B     3        9     name1
```

My expected result is:

```
LBL       Var1      Var2   newLBL
name1       1        12    name1
name1_A     1        13    name1
name1_B     2        10    name1
name2       1        11    name2
name2_A     2        10    name2
name2_B     3        9     name2
```

But just can't seem to get it to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only taking the first element from `y`, you want the first column with `y[,1]`:

```
remExt <- function(x){
  y <- str_split_fixed(x,"_",2)
  return(y[,1])
}

df %>% mutate(newLBL = remExt(LBL))
      LBL Var1 Var2 newLBL
1   name1    1   12  name1
2 name1_A    1   13  name1
3 name1_B    2   10  name1
4   name2    1   11  name2
5 name2_A    2   10  name2
6 name2_B    3    9  name2
```

Also note with `mutate` you don't need to extract the column with `$`

**EDIT:**

A simpler implementation would be to use `str_remove` or `str_replace`. Both the following are equivalent:

```
df %>% mutate(newLBL = str_replace(LBL,"\\_.",""))

df %>% mutate(newLBL = str_remove(LBL,"\\_."))
```